# Changing views and setting labels have unexpected consequences

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller

Sorry for the waffley title.

I have an issue with my iOS app. I use this code to change view controller and set some labels texts:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *date = cell.textLabel.text;
NSString *entry = cell.detailTextLabel.text;

if (self.detailsViewController == nil) 
{
 DiaryDetailsViewController *d = [[DiaryDetailsViewController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"DiaryDetailsViewController"
                                      bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 self.detailsViewController = d;
}
[self.detailsViewController setTexts:date entry:entry];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsViewController 
                                                  animated:YES];
```

The code for setTexts is:

```
 -(void) setTexts:(NSString *)date entry:(NSString *)entry 
 {
  [self.dateLabel setText:date];
  [self.entryLabel setText:entry];
 }​
```

This code does not work the first time the view is changed, so all the labels are left blank, but it does change the label texts next the next time the view changes.

I know something is wrong here, but can't seem to find it, so what is going on here? Why is the text not changing the first time the view opens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because view of  DiaryDetailsViewController is nil. You should update labels after view controller is pushed to navContoller.

```
DiaryDetailsViewController *d = [[DiaryDetailsViewController alloc] initWithText:cell.textLabel.text detailText:cell.detailTextLabel.text;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

...

add property for 2 variables text and detail

```
- (id)initWithText:(NSString *)text detailText:(NSString *)detail {
...
self.text = text;
self.detailText = detail;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
```

....

```
  [self.dateLabel setText:text];
  [self.entryLabel setText:detailText ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calling it first time than you have to first call your

*[self.detailsViewController setTexts:date entry:entry];* this methods that view load so its not showing but second time object id loaded memory before. so its call showing proper.
[for solving the problem you have to call it after pushing the viewcontoller